# add_theme_page to add_menu_page theme options convert

Tags: php

```
<?php

/**
 * ILC Tabbed Settings Page
 */

  add_action( 'init', 'ilc_admin_init' );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ilc_settings_page_init' );

    function ilc_admin_init() {
        $settings = get_option( "ilc_theme_settings" );
        if ( empty( $settings ) ) {
            $settings = array(
                'ilc_intro' => 'Some intro text for the home page',
                'ilc_tag_class' => false,
                'ilc_ga' => false
            );
            add_option( "ilc_theme_settings", $settings, '', 'yes' );
        }   
    }

    function ilc_settings_page_init() {
        $theme_data = get_theme_data( TEMPLATEPATH . '/style.css' );
        $settings_page = add_theme_page( $theme_data['Name']. ' Theme Settings', $theme_data['Name']. ' Theme Settings', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme-settings', 'ilc_settings_page' );
        add_action( "load-{$settings_page}", 'ilc_load_settings_page' );
    }

    function ilc_load_settings_page() {
        if ( $_POST["ilc-settings-submit"] == 'Y' ) {
            check_admin_referer( "ilc-settings-page" );
            ilc_save_theme_settings();
            $url_parameters = isset($_GET['tab'])? 'updated=true&tab='.$_GET['tab'] : 'updated=true';
            wp_redirect(admin_url('themes.php?page=theme-settings&'.$url_parameters));
            exit;
        }
    }

    function ilc_save_theme_settings() {
        global $pagenow;
        $settings = get_option( "ilc_theme_settings" );

        if ( $pagenow == 'themes.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'theme-settings' ){ 
            if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) )
                $tab = $_GET['tab']; 
            else
                $tab = 'homepage'; 

            switch ( $tab ){ 
                case 'general' :
                    $settings['ilc_tag_class']    = $_POST['ilc_tag_class'];
                break; 
                case 'footer' : 
                    $settings['ilc_ga']  = $_POST['ilc_ga'];
                break;
                case 'homepage' : 
                    $settings['ilc_intro']    = $_POST['ilc_intro'];
                break;
            }
        }

        if( !current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ){
            if ( $settings['ilc_ga']  )
                $settings['ilc_ga'] = stripslashes( esc_textarea( wp_filter_post_kses( $settings['ilc_ga'] ) ) );
            if ( $settings['ilc_intro'] )
                $settings['ilc_intro'] = stripslashes( esc_textarea( wp_filter_post_kses( $settings['ilc_intro'] ) ) );
        }

        $updated = update_option( "ilc_theme_settings", $settings );
    }

    function ilc_admin_tabs( $current = 'homepage' ) { 
        $tabs = array( 'homepage' => 'Home', 'general' => 'General', 'footer' => 'Footer' ); 
        $links = array();
        echo '<div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"><br></div>';
        echo '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">';
        foreach( $tabs as $tab => $name ){
            $class = ( $tab == $current ) ? ' nav-tab-active' : '';
            echo "<a class='nav-tab$class' href='?page=theme-settings&tab=$tab'>$name</a>";

        }
        echo '</h2>';
    }

    function ilc_settings_page() {
        global $pagenow;
        $settings = get_option( "ilc_theme_settings" );
        $theme_data = get_theme_data( TEMPLATEPATH . '/style.css' );
        ?>

        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php echo $theme_data['Name']; ?> Theme Settings</h2>

            <?php
                if ( 'true' == esc_attr( $_GET['updated'] ) ) echo '<div class="updated" ><p>Theme Settings updated.</p></div>';

                if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) ) ilc_admin_tabs($_GET['tab']); else ilc_admin_tabs('homepage');
            ?>

            <div id="poststuff">
                <form method="post" action="<?php admin_url( 'themes.php?page=theme-settings' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    wp_nonce_field( "ilc-settings-page" ); 

                    if ( $pagenow == 'themes.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'theme-settings' ){ 

                        if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) ) $tab = $_GET['tab']; 
                        else $tab = 'homepage'; 

                        echo '<table class="form-table">';
                        switch ( $tab ){
                            case 'general' :
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><label for="ilc_tag_class">Tags with CSS classes:</label></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="ilc_tag_class" name="ilc_tag_class" type="checkbox" <?php if ( $settings["ilc_tag_class"] ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" /> 
                                        <span class="description">Output each post tag with a specific CSS class using its slug.</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            break; 
                            case 'footer' : 
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><label for="ilc_ga">Insert tracking code:</label></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id="ilc_ga" name="ilc_ga" cols="60" rows="5"><?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $settings["ilc_ga"] ) ); ?></textarea><br/>
                                        <span class="description">Enter your Google Analytics tracking code:</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            break;
                            case 'homepage' : 
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><label for="ilc_intro">Introduction</label></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea id="ilc_intro" name="ilc_intro" cols="60" rows="5" ><?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $settings["ilc_intro"] ) ); ?></textarea><br/>
                                        <span class="description">Enter the introductory text for the home page:</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            break;
                        }
                        echo '</table>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <p class="submit" style="clear: both;">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit"  class="button-primary" value="Update Settings" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="ilc-settings-submit" value="Y" />
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p><?php echo $theme_data['Name'] ?> theme by <a href="http://ilovecolors.com.ar/">ilovecolors.com.ar</a> | <a href="http://twitter.com/eliorivero">Follow me on Twitter</a>! | Join <a href="http://on.fb.me/ilcfb">ilovecolors on Facebook</a>!</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

This is my theme page option which is under appearance menu. I Want add this option to under menu page. please help me.

Comment: Your code is extremely full of bugs, and you are using depreciated functions. Please set debug to true in wp-config. Also go and have a look at these pages. [Creating Options Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) and [add options page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page)